# Ler Json no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, java, html, json

Tenho o seguinte código no meu `PHP`:

```
<?php

  $url = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/destaques";

  $response =  file_get_contents($url); 
  $jogadores = json_decode($response,true);
```

Ele deveria retorna o arquivo `json`, onde pego as informações e monto em outra página e isso funcionava até um tempo atras, mas parou. e absolutamente nada foi mudado.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

---

Quando uso:

```
var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
```

Ele só retorna `NULL`

Comment: Não está dando o erro `failed to open stream` usando a função `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Deu sim :/ mas com a resposta do amigo abaixo, funcionou :)

Comment: Nesses casos, quando aparece a mensagem de erro, coloque-a junto com a pergunta, pois facilita quem for te ajudar a entender o problema. Neste caso não foi crucial, pois seria o erro mais óbvio, mas nem sempre é assim, então faça isso em possíveis perguntas futuras.

Comment: Blz Anderson, mas a questão do erro Failed to open... só apareceu em um dos meus servidores, no principal onde a aplicação roda não apresentou esse erro, simplesmente retornava NULL sem mostrar erro nenhum, agradeço. abraçoo

Comment: Deve ser a configuração deste servidor para ocultar as mensagens de erro. Geralmente servidores que rodam em produção são configurados assim para evitar vazar alguma informação a usuários maliciosos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure o `USERAGENT` com o paramentro `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)`, tanto com [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) ou [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-init.php):

Com [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
<?php

    $url = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/destaques";

    $options = array(
        'http' => 
          array(
            'method' => 'GET', 
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)', 
            'timeout' => 1
            )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $sol = json_decode($file, true);    
    var_dump($sol);
```

Com [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-init.php):

```
<?php

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/destaques',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl); 
    $sol = json_decode($result, true);  
    var_dump($sol);
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-init.php)
- [User agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

Comment: Opa funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado :) você acha melhor usar o file_get_contents ou Curl ?

Comment: Outro detalhe se você olhar --> https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/destaques vai ver o numero de escalações e os valores não batem kkk exemplo ai na api o jogador arrascaeta está com 478.000 escalaçoes mas quando monto a estrutura aqui --> www.fccartolaclub.com.br ele aparece com 480.000 não só ele mas os outros jogadores tbm, ta dando uma diferença de 2 a 3 mil a mais

Comment: @AndréLuizMardonis bom ter ajudado, agora os dados obtidos foge da nossa programação, porque vem de um api, verifique junto ao site o porque disso, e se o problema foi resolvido aceite como resposta!